# Disable IE Context Menu

Tags: internet-explorer

Is there a way to disable the right-click context menu in Internet Explorer?  I want it to be disabled globally, not just per page.  I do not control the websites that will be visited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Start Regedit
2. Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ Software \ Policies \ Microsoft \ Internet Explorer \ Restrictions
3. Add a DWORD with a name of:

   NoBrowserContextMenu  1

see also:

http://www.onecomputerguy.com/ie_tips.htm

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc960644.aspx